# Fetching image issue in Afnetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

I am new in iOS world.I am reading tutorial on afnetworking but i have some issue while i have to fetch images from server.I follow this tutorial :-

https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

I got error when i write this code :-

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                      placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
```

error message :- no visible @interface for declares the selector setImageWithURLRequest such....

**I have already import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"**

Please help or provide me some link where i can learn fetch and uploading images to/from via Afnetworking.

Comment: I would suggest you to use SDWebImageView to display images from server with URL, it is pretty  simple and better at performance, what so far i have used.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request,   NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
if (weakCell)
{
    weakCell.imageView.image = image;
    [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
}
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```